# Is there a way to get all the entities inside SaveChanges method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

1. I am trying to mark the objects for deletion.
2. I have overridden the Savechnages method, and want to get all the entities regardless of their state. The code below is take from a site, the problem is the objects whose properties have not been changed, and simply marked for deletion don't show up.

   ```
   public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   {
       var deletedEntities = __getDeletedEntities();
       _softDelete(deletedEntities);
       return base.SaveChanges(options);
   }

   private List<ISoftDelete> __getDeletedEntities()
   {

      return ObjectStateManager
                .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged)
                       .Select(entry => entry.Entity)
                       .OfType<ISoftDelete>()
                       .Where(e => e.IsDeleted)
                       .ToList();
   ```

   }

Q: Is there any other way rather than using GetObjectStateEntries, to get all entities regardless of state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityState is a flags enums which means that you can combine multiple values when invoking GetObjectStateEntries like this:

```
ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged | EntityState.Deleted)
```

On the other hand since the deleted entities are already marked as deleted they will be sent to the database anyways for deletion so I am not sure what you are going to do with them.

Comment: Pawel. I tried alot for implemeting soft delete and finally gave up and doing a physical delete. My BLL objects have IsDeleted property, since Database doesn't have column IsDeleted, so I've implementd and interface on the POCO classes to know if the object has been deleted. I don't want the BLL to have reference to ObjectContext and invoke DeleteObject method. So BLL simply flags the POCO object for deletion and then in the SaveChanges method, I detect the flag and explicitly call DeleteObject on those object.

Comment: @BrikeshKumar Just for the sake of interest, why are you "reinveinting the wheel" trying to delete objects manually? Isn't it the responsibility of the ORM to do that for us? On the other hand, if you don't use the offerings of "civilization" why don't you use plain old SQL?

Comment: @Oybek Yes it is the OR/M's responsibility. I dont want it to do magic and give me no control.I wasted couple of days trying to learn a soft delete using EF, such a simple thing. Either I was nuts, not able to learn or only some zen at the EF team can understand. Anyways I would prefer to use iBatis.Net and yes it would give me full control on the SQL.

Comment: @BrikeshKumar Can you tell we what exactly do you mean by 'soft delete'? Does that mean to delete objects without retrieving them first or something else?